# Need help on padding hex and some conversions

Tags: c++, c, string, hex, string-formatting

I will briefly explain what I want to do and help appreciated.

I have a hex number which is formatted as 16 byte number like this:

```
1: std::string myhex = "00000000000000000000000000000FFD";
```

Then I want to convert it to int. Which I think I successfully do using this:

```
// convert hex to int
unsigned int x = strtoul(myhex.c_str(), NULL, 16);
printf("x = %d\n", x); // prints 4093 as needed
```

Now, I want to convert this integer back to hex. Which I think I also successfully do using this:

```
// Convert int back to hex
char buff[50];
string hexval;
sprintf(buff,"%x",x);
hexval = buff;
cout << hexval.c_str(); // prints "ffd".
```

But my problem is that now, I want to convert the "ffd" string as above back to the format it was before, e.g., 16 byte number padded with zeros like this:

```
00000000000000000000000000000FFD
```

I want to convert the string not only print it.

Any help how to do this?
Also any corrections if anything I was achieving above is wrong or not OK are welcome.
Preferably I would like this to compile on Linux also.

Comment: So your question is not about conversion, but about how to format a string containing the hexadecimal representation of an integer to have leading zeroes? Did you read the `sprintf` documentation? Please try to keep your question concise and less open-ended. _"I would like this to compile on Linux also"_ seems strange since you'd never mentioned that you were using Windows, before this point. Good luck!

Comment: It is pretty unclear why you insist on encoding 16-byte values in hex and think it is acceptable to use a conversion function that can only only 4 or 8 bytes.  You are pursuing the garbage-in-garbage-out fallacy.  Same kind of fallacy as displaying more than 15 digits for a double.  Those extra digits on the right don't mean anything.  Just as those extra zeros on the left in your case don't mean anything.  So don't bother displaying them.  And give your user a break.

Comment: Hans is right — `unsigned long` is not big enough for this task, so your use of `strtoul` is incorrect, unfortunately.

Comment: @HansPassant: This is not for the user. Just where I must store this variable only accepts 16 bytes. Also I don't think that number - stored in `myhex` - will be very large, e.g., more than 4 bytes.. What do you think in such case?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: please see my above comment

Comment: You are very confused.  Hex is for humans, computers use 0 and 1's.  It is not like you can't find one that can handle 128 bit integers, there's a friendly IBM dealer that can sell you one.  There are "big integer" libraries around a-plenty for constrained budgets.  In the end, the only thing that matters is that the number actually means something.  Going past a quintillion take some effort to keep your user interested in the result.

Comment: @HansPassant: I'm not sure I get you, why am I confused? please look at my initial string named `myhex`. I said indeed it is represented as 16 byte number but in reality I said I doubt it will be larger than say 4 bytes - it is just padded like that because it has to be 16 bytes in order for me to be able to save it where I am saving (on a device)

Comment: Just change the first digit from a 0 to a 1.  Does it still work?  No.  So what was the point of displaying that 0?

Comment: Where? Do you mean on my 1st line? (I added line indicator now). The reason I am padding is that when I store this value on a device, it *must* be 16 bytes, did I make it clear now?

Comment: If you only need 4 bytes of precision, even though your representation must be longer for external reasons beyond your control, then this is fine.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Thank you for your response, indeed I don't think the number there will be more than 8 bytes. So you say for that purposes above code seems ok. That said, I need to find out now, actually why I am storing the number in hex in the first place - the device where I store it, just needs an array of 16 bytes... what would be most convenient way to store an `int` inside? -- I may later open a separate question about it also ...

Answer (score 2):

Use the `0` flag (prefix) for zero-padding and field width specification in a `printf`:

```
printf("%032X", x);
```

Use `snprintf` to store it in your string:

```
snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%032X", x);
```

Or use `asprintf` to store it in a newly-allocated string, to be certain that the memory available for the string is sufficient (since it's allocated by `asprintf`):

```
char *as_string = NULL;
asprintf(&as_string, "%032X", x);
```

Comment: Thanks Ted, but that will just print it right? I merely want to obtain a new string padded.. what to use now? Also would be nice to hear what you think about my other parts of code as I mentioned in my post ..

Comment: Updated answer to indicate alternate `printf`-like functions for string formatting rather than output. In particular you should use `asprintf()` rather than `snprintf()` if you want to automatically have a buffer that is big enough. You still need to check for errors in both cases (ie. check the return code of `snprintf` or `asprintf`).

Comment: Ok, ted and what is x in your case - is it integer? just in my case the number `ffd` which I want to pad is stored in string ...

Comment: `x` is your `unsigned int x` variable.

Comment: Thanks it seems also there is no need to convert the int to hex as I did in second step..

Comment: @dmcr_code: The "X" format code in `*printf` performs the rendering to hex. (Please don't call it "converting to hex", though; you're not "converting" anything; when stored in memory, the number is physically binary (in RAM/cache/register/swap) and lexically decimal (if seen as a literal in your code) but semantically has _no base_; it's only for rendering to a string that you choose a base and, in this case, you're choosing hexadecimal.)